# Как оптимизировать множество условий через функцию?

Tags: javascript

Совсем запутался. Не подскажете, как оптимизировать данную программу?
Она меняет цену в зависимости от даты. Но в ней есть минус - в ней много условий.

Не знаю, как облегчить ее.

```js
$.ajax('./', {
        type: 'HEAD'
    })
    .always(function (a, b, c) {
        var getResponseHeader = (a && a.getResponseHeader) || (c && c.getResponseHeader);


        var currentDatePre = getResponseHeader('Date');

        var currentDate = moment(currentDatePre).subtract(10, 'days').calendar();


        var dd = parseInt(currentDate.split('/')[1]) + 10;

        var mm = parseInt(currentDate.split('/')[0]);

        var yyyy = parseInt(currentDate.split('/')[2])

        if (dd < 10) {
            dd = '0' + dd;
        }

        if (mm < 10) {
            mm = '0' + mm;
        }

 
        var todaysdate = '11/11/2019';

        console.log(todaysdate)

        var date1 = ['31/10/2019','29/10/2019','30/10/2019'];
        var date2 = ['01/11/2019','02/11/2019','03/11/2019','04/11/2019']
        var date3 = ['05/11/2019','06/11/2019','07/11/2019']
        var date4 = ['08/11/2019','09/11/2019','10/11/2019']
        var date5 = ['11/11/2019','12/11/2019','13/11/2019','14/11/2019']
        var date6 = ['15/11/2019','16/11/2019','17/11/2019']
        var date7 = ['18/11/2019','19/11/2019','20/11/2019','21/11/2019']
        var date8 = ['22/11/2019','23/11/2019','24/11/2019']
        var date9 = ['25/11/2019']
        var date10 = ['26/11/2019','27/11/2019','28/11/2019','29/11/2019','30/11/2019']

        var checkDate1 = date1.indexOf(todaysdate)
        var checkDate2 = date2.indexOf(todaysdate)
        var checkDate3 = date3.indexOf(todaysdate)
        var checkDate4 = date4.indexOf(todaysdate)
        var checkDate5 = date5.indexOf(todaysdate)
        var checkDate6 = date6.indexOf(todaysdate)
        var checkDate7 = date7.indexOf(todaysdate)
        var checkDate8 = date8.indexOf(todaysdate)
        var checkDate9 = date9.indexOf(todaysdate)
        var checkDate10 = date10.indexOf(todaysdate)

        if (checkDate1 > -1){
      
            document.getElementById('currentPrice').innerHTML = '2339 рублей в месяц';
        } 
        if(checkDate2 > -1){
          
            document.getElementById('currentPrice').innerHTML = '2107 рублей в месяц';
        } 
        if(checkDate3 > -1){
         
            document.getElementById('currentPrice').innerHTML = '2339 рублей в месяц';
        }
         if(checkDate4 > -1){
        
            document.getElementById('currentPrice').innerHTML = '2107 рублей в месяц';
        }
        if(checkDate5 > -1){
       
            document.getElementById('currentPrice').innerHTML = '2339 рублей в месяц';
        }
         if(checkDate6 > -1){
         
            document.getElementById('currentPrice').innerHTML = '2107  рублей в месяц';
        }
         if(checkDate7 > -1){
         
            document.getElementById('currentPrice').innerHTML = '2339 рублей в месяц';
        } 
        if(checkDate8 > -1){
           
            document.getElementById('currentPrice').innerHTML = '2107 рублей в месяц';
        } 
         if(checkDate9 > -1){
     
            document.getElementById('currentPrice').innerHTML = '2339 рублей в месяц';
        } 
        if(checkDate10 > -1){
      
            document.getElementById('currentPrice').innerHTML = '2339 рублей в месяц';
        }
         


    });
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

        <p id="oldPrice"></p>
        <p id="currentPrice"></p>

    </div>
```

Comment: Очевидное решение - вместо отдельных переменных делать... ну хотя бы массив.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так можно

```js
$.ajax('./', {
        type: 'HEAD'
    })
    .always(function (a, b, c) {
        var getResponseHeader = (a && a.getResponseHeader) || (c && c.getResponseHeader),
            currentDatePre = getResponseHeader('Date'),
            currentDate = moment(currentDatePre).subtract(10, 'days').calendar(),
            dd = setDate(parseInt(currentDate.split('/')[1]) + 10),
            mm = setDate(parseInt(currentDate.split('/')[0])),
            yyyy = parseInt(currentDate.split('/')[2]),
            todaysdate = '11/11/2019',
            dates = [
              [['31/10/2019','29/10/2019','30/10/2019'],'2339'],
              [['01/11/2019','02/11/2019','03/11/2019','04/11/2019'],'2107'],
              [['05/11/2019','06/11/2019','07/11/2019'],'2339'],
              [['08/11/2019','09/11/2019','10/11/2019'],'2107'],
              [['11/11/2019','12/11/2019','13/11/2019','14/11/2019'],'2339'],
              [['15/11/2019','16/11/2019','17/11/2019'],'2107'],
              [['18/11/2019','19/11/2019','20/11/2019','21/11/2019'],'2339'],
              [['22/11/2019','23/11/2019','24/11/2019'],'2107'],
              [['25/11/2019'],'2339'],
              [['26/11/2019','27/11/2019','28/11/2019','29/11/2019','30/11/2019'],'2339']
            ];
        checkDates(dates,todaysdate);
    });
    
function setDate(date){
  return date<10?'0'+date:date;
}

function checkDate(dates) {
  let price = document.getElementById('currentPrice');
  dates.forEach(function(elem){
    if(elem[0].indexOf(todaysdate) > -1){
      price.innerHTML = elem[1]+' рублей в месяц';
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p id="oldPrice"></p>
  <p id="currentPrice"></p>
</div>
```